# How to beautifully make some API functions available only to authorized users in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have functions in my API code, some of which should only return requested results only to those requests that have a correct token. If the request is not authorized, then return a generic 401 response.

I have created a helper function `is_authorised()` which returns true/false.

Now, in a function that I want to make accessible only to authorized users, I check the result of the `is_authorised()` function and return respective response.

Here is an example:

```
get_players(SessionID, _Env, _Input) ->
    case is_authorized(_Env) of
        true ->
            Response = [json_header(), players:select_all()];
        false ->
            Response = get_unauthorized_response()
    end,
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Response).
```

I wonder if it's possible to make this checking look more elegant, like Python decorators used in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/98/).

```
@app.route('/user')
@required_roles('admin', 'user')
def user_page(self):
    return "You've got permission to access this page."
```

I know I can't use custom functions in guards, so I think it's not possible to make it as a guard.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as elegant as Python decorators, but you can use higher order functions to make this much cleaner. Create a function that accepts `SessionID`, `Env`, `Input`, and a callback function that should be executed when the user is authorized, and call that from all the functions that need to do the authorization check.

(Untested) code:

```
authorized(SessionID, Env, Input, Fun) ->
    Response = case is_authorized(Env) of
        true ->
            Fun();
        false ->
            get_unauthorized_response()
    end,
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Response).

get_players(SessionID, Env, Input) ->
    authorized(SessionID, Env, Input, fun() ->
        [json_header(), players:select_all()]
    end).
```

You can pass more arguments to `authorized` if you want to do more extensive checks. With a `role_of/1` function that accepts `Env` and returns the role as an atom, you can allow access to certain users with something like this:

```
authorized(SessionID, Env, Input, Roles, Fun) ->
    Response = case lists:member(role_of(Env), Roles) of
        true ->
            Fun();
        false ->
            get_unauthorized_response()
    end,
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Response).

get_players(SessionID, Env, Input) ->
    authorized(SessionID, Env, Input, [admin, user], fun() ->
        [json_header(), players:select_all()]
    end).
```

Comment: I thought about this approach too, seems like I will use, looks good enough, thanks!

Comment: @SergeiBasharov please also see my edit. This way you can probably emulate the behavior of that Python snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into cowboy or webmachine as they'd give you a framework over a state machine to handle REST requests. Implement the 'forbidden/2' callback to indicate unauthorized access.

On a side note: a 401 status code indicates a failure of authentication at the http layer when doing one of the well known http auth mechanisms like basic. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
What you are dealing with is a authorization failure and the correct associated http status code for that case would be 403 (as the forbidden callback from above would return).